# How to pass user name to the DB Connection during connection establishment by Hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss

I need to pass currently logged username to the DB Connection, because I want to trace user changes and store it in Oracle DB with correct user name. I am using Hibernate on my JBoss 5.1 and Oracle 11g database.

I think I need to do something like this ([SOURCE](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_session.php#end_to_end_tracing_java)):

```java
try {
    String e2eMetrics[] = new String[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_STATE_INDEX_MAX];
    e2eMetrics[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_CLIENTID_INDEX] = System.getProperty("user.name");
    ((OracleConnection) conn).setEndToEndMetrics(e2eMetrics, (short) 0);
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    // Do something...
}
```

### Problem:

The problem is that I do not have an idea how/where to call it to pass some value to the connection. I mean where, in which moment I should inject this code, because I am using hibernate and EntityManagerFactory and I do not create connection manually, so I do not have access to connection object itself. I need to call it only once for whole user connection and remove username after connection release.

### Expected goal:

My goal is to pass String (actual username) from java code or hibernate configuration to Oracle DB under 'client_info' column in `v$session` table, just after/during connection establishment which is done by hibernate.

I know that the value can be passed by [`DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm#CHEJCFGG) procedure and I even checked it with code below, but the main question is how to call it only once for whole connection at connection establishment in hibernate?

Working Test for passing value to the `v$session` table to 'client_info' column:

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public void setDBClientInfo(String clientInfo) {
    try {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("{call SYS.dbms_application_info.set_client_info(:userName)}")
                .setParameter("userName", clientInfo);
        query.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### My Configuration:

spring-servlet.xml:

```xml
<!-- DataSource -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MynameDS" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- TransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="MyUnitName" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/MyNameDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.mydomain.model.Assignment</class>
    <class>com.mydomain.model.AuditLog</class>
    <class>com.mydomain.model.Person</class>
    <class>com.mydomain.model.Trial</class>
    <class>com.mydomain.model.Violation</class>

    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Is it possible to do via hibernate configuration or via Java code?

Please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: This does not sound like a sound idea. I wouldn't want to have to give every user R/W access to my database.  If you want to track users, why not just create a audit table?

Comment: I have an existing audit log table but changes on it are detected by sql procedures. All I need to do is only pass the user name some how to the `v$session` and sql procedures will do rest (tracking changes is already implemented).

Comment: I still think its a bad idea to pass user credentials to the underlying DB, but I did find this: http://affy.blogspot.com/2006/12/per-user-connection-pooling-for-spring.html